# Получение среднего цвета изображения

Tags: любой-язык, цвета

Слушал приложение Windows "Музыка Groove". И тут я заметил интересную вещь: приложение брало изображение саундтрека и аддитивным смещением вычисляло средний цвет всего изображения.

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sub>Саундтреки MARVEL были взяты для примера.</sub>

Как это можно реализовать? Подойдут решения на `WPF`, `Windows Forms`, `ASP.NET` или просто на `HTML`/`CSS`/`Javascript`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84863/discussion-on-question-by-ver-nick----).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python-скрипт на основе примера из документации [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html#color-quantization):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from collections import Counter


def get_dominant_color(image, k=4):
    image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))
    clt = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    labels = clt.fit_predict(image)
    label_counts = Counter(labels)
    dominant_color = clt.cluster_centers_[label_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]]
    return list(dominant_color)


bgr_image = cv2.imread('image.png')
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
dom_color = get_dominant_color(hsv_image)
dom_color_hsv = np.full(bgr_image.shape, dom_color, dtype='uint8')
dom_color_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(dom_color_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
output_image = np.hstack((bgr_image, dom_color_bgr))
cv2.imshow('Dominant Color', output_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Скрипт на `python` используя `pillow`, реализацию переписал с [статьи хабра](https://habr.com/ru/post/419309/), из [библиотеки на javascript fast-average-color](https://github.com/fast-average-color/fast-average-color/blob/15561aa55a36702f0b1af3d0ef611a205f8d56b5/src/algorithm/sqrt.js#L3) (кст, эта библиотека подходит под ваше условие в вопросе ).

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/ec1f4102d0c15efb98e9e5e0d4497c5978ea707d/pil_pillow__examples/fast_average_color)

```
import math
from typing import Tuple
from pathlib import Path

from PIL import Image


DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def get_mode_correction(image: Image) -> str:
    if image.mode not in ['RGB', 'RGBA']:
        return 'RGB'
    return image.mode


def sqrt_algorithm(image: Image) -> Tuple[int, int, int, int]:
    mode = get_mode_correction(image)
    if mode != image.mode:
        image = image.convert('RGB')

    red_total = 0
    green_total = 0
    blue_total = 0
    alpha_total = 0
    count = 0

    pixel = image.load()

    for i in range(image.width):
        for j in range(image.height):
            color = pixel[i, j]
            if len(color) == 4:
                red, green, blue, alpha = color
            else:
                [red, green, blue], alpha = color, 255

            red_total += red * red * alpha
            green_total += green * green * alpha
            blue_total += blue * blue * alpha
            alpha_total += alpha

            count += 1

    return (
        round(math.sqrt(red_total / alpha_total)),
        round(math.sqrt(green_total / alpha_total)),
        round(math.sqrt(blue_total / alpha_total)),
        round(alpha_total / count)
    )


def draw_example(image: Image, margin=70) -> Image:
    rgba = sqrt_algorithm(image)

    width = image.width + margin + margin
    height = image.height + margin + margin

    mode = get_mode_correction(image)

    image_output = Image.new(mode, (width, height), rgba)
    image_output.paste(image, (margin, margin))

    return image_output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for file_name in DIR.glob('input/*.*'):
        image = Image.open(file_name)
        image_output = draw_example(image)
        # image_output.show()
        image_output.save(DIR / 'output' / file_name.name)
```

Результат для нескольких картинок из папки скрипта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У нее mode = L, это `(8-bit pixels, black and white)`, сделаю доработку, по которой будет определяться mode и принудительно сделаю конвертацию в RGB

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, готово :)